# Can't split the_title() by white space

Tags: templates, title

I am having issues splitting `the_title()` by white space in my template.

```
$title_split = explode(" ", trim(the_title()));
```

and (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206953/split-string-by-white-space)

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

(To be clear I'm not using preg as was shown but customized for my use, it was just the first thing I found when looking for a "proper")

Both produce an empty array on the phrase `2022 Theme Challenge`.

I have also made sure the output uses white spaces, which it does. The template produces:

```
<h2 class="post-title">2022 Theme Challenge</h2>
```

I am trying to replace the first word in a title with encapsulating `<span>` tags to style it greeen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you tried should work if you use `get_the_title()` instead. It’s because get_the_title returns the title, whereas `the_title()` function echos the title by default.

```
$title_split = explode(" ", trim(get_the_title()));
```

Comment: Oh thank you! That explains that a lot. I suppose I should have caught the whole echo bit from the functions source on WordPress's docu. Oops.